# jqModal and ad-gallery

Tags: jqmodal

This is just driving me nuts. I am trying jqModal work with jquery.ad-gallery. This is what I have so far:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqModal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ad-gallery.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.ad-gallery.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqModal.js" ></script>
 <script>
 $().ready(function() {

  $('#jqmPix').jqm({modal:true});

 showPix = function(bhiid,projNum) {
   $.ajax({
           type: "get",        
           url: "<cfoutput>#actURL#</cfoutput>",
           cache: false,       
           success: function(result) { 
                $('#jqmPixTitle').html('Photos for : '+projNum);
                $('#jqmPixText').html(result);
                $('#jqmPix').jqmShow().css('left',getTopLeftPt('#jqmPix')).css('top',getTop('#jqmPix'));
                },

           error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
             confirm('Error!' + err );
         }
      });
    }

     getTopLeftPt = function(a){
        var leftPt = parseInt($(window).width()/2)-parseInt($(a).width()/2);
       //alert(leftPt);
       return leftPt;
       }
     getTop = function(a){
      var topPt = parseInt($(window).height()/4-50);
      //alert(topPt);
      return topPt;
     }



 });
  </script>

  <input type="button" name="clicky" id="clicky" value="clicky" onclick="showPix(40852,'RE5540T09608B')"/>


 <div id="jqmPix" class="jqmWindow" style="width:690px; display:none;">
<div class="jqmHeader" >
    <div id="jqmPixTitle"></div>
    <div id="jqmHeaderClose" >
        <img src="images/vista-close.gif" class="jqmClose" alt="close" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="jqmBody">
   <div id="jqmPixText"  align="center">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="jqmFooter jqmFooterButtons" id="jqmFooterText">
</div>
```

I see the modal window, the navigation underneath the image container but the main image is missing. IT just doesn't display.

The funny thing is if I go to the ajax url directly, everything works perfectly fine. One trick is that i have to pass a url variable and check for its existence when i hit the ajax url directly. If it exists, then i include . Otherwise, firebug throws an error on jqmShow() on the calling page.

can anybody help me?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with .ad-image definition in jquery.ad-gallery.css and/or _showWhenLoaded function in jquery.ad-gallery.css. I found another plug-in called galleria. I had one problem where I have to refresh the main page with : parent.location.reload(1);

Otherwise, it goes into an endless loop when you reopen the jqmodal window. Anyway, hope this helps to someone else.